# How to use external Web Components in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, web-component

I am trying to figure out how Web Components developed by others (external to my app) could be used in my app.
I have a UsefullComponent which I would like to use in my AppWithComponent. 
The UsefullComponent (UsefullComponent.js) is stored in a directory called 'componentsLib', while my application code is store in directory called 'myApp'.
I have also my index.html which imports 'myApp'.
The whole thing compiles (I use TypeScript) but at run time I get an error 'GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/componentsLib/UsefullComponent 404 (Not Found)'.
Any idea of what I do wrong?

Here the code

**UsefullComponent.ts**

```
import {bootstrap, Component, FORM_DIRECTIVES, 
   CORE_DIRECTIVES, Input} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'usefull-component',
    providers: [],
    template: `
        <div>
            <h2>My manifesto</h2>
            <h3>{{manifesto}}</h3>
        </div>
        `,
    styleUrls: [],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class UsefullComponent { 
    public manifesto: string = 'I am a very usefull component';
}
```

**AppWithComponent.ts**

```
import {bootstrap, Component, FORM_DIRECTIVES, 
        CORE_DIRECTIVES, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {UsefullComponent} from '../../componentsLib/UsefullComponent';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app-with-comp',
    providers: [UsefullComponent],
    template: `
        <div>
            <h1>I use components</h1>
            <usefull-component></usefull-component>
        </div>
        `,
    styleUrls: [],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, UsefullComponent]
})
class AppWithComponent { 
    public niceComponent: UsefullComponent;

    constructor(inComponent: UsefullComponent) {
        this.niceComponent = inComponent;
    }
}
bootstrap(AppWithComponent);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Components</title>
<script src="../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<script>
System.config({
        packages: {'myApp': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
});
      System.import('myApp/myAppWithComp');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<my-app-with-comp>loading...</my-app-with-comp>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. As per my knowledge we should add below two lines in file myApp/myAppWithComp
   bootstrap(AppWithComponent);bootstrap(UsefullComponent);
2. And remove bootstrap(AppWithComponent); from file AppWithComponent.ts
3. And add `<div>` tag in the index.html file as below

   ```
   <body><div><my-app-with-comp>loading...</my-app-with-comp></div></body>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake I see with your code is the path to the components lib. Check if you have UsefullComponent.js is being placed at /componentsLib/UsefullComponent.js

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10660735)

Comment: I'm newbie here and StackOverflow says I don't have any reputation to comment :(

Comment: Thanks Rajiran. I have checked and UsefullComponent.js is actually located at /componentsLib/UsefullComponent.js; I will give some more tries to see if I can find what's wrong

Comment: @rajkiran Once you have sufficient reputation, you can comment on any post. Until then, please realize that your answer is expected to fully address the question.